# Como hacer para que Firebase solo permita iniciar sesión?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, oauth2

Necesito que Firebase solo inicie sesion, no que cree cuenta,

```
angularFireAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
```

Esa función no me sirve, si el usuario no existe lo crea igual lo cual no es correcto. Si me dan ideas se lo agradezco. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes la opción de crear usuarios desde Firebase y utilizar la autenticación con email y contraseña (les pones una temporal y que la cambien).

En Angular usas el método

```
firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

Espero que te sea útil.

Comment: Gracias, sirve de ayuda!